# What are the simply-connected non-compact irreducible symmetric spaces?

Tags: lie-groups, symmetric-spaces

> Would someone be able to list (or provide a reference to) the simply-connected non-compact irreducible symmetric spaces of rank $\ge 1$(as quotients of Lie groups $G/H$)?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Wolf ([2011](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2742530)), [p. 286 sq.](https://books.google.com/books?id=8qoJBAAAQBAJ&ots=5Qb7rT5H6L&pg=PA286).

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Question: When it says "duality interchanges compact and non-compact simply connected irreducible symmetric spaces further reducing the classification to the compact irreducible case", does this mean that a decomposition of a, say non-compact, symmetric space must have irreducible factors that are compact simple simply connected Lie groups?

Comment: I don’t get how this pertains to your question. You are assuming $M$ irreducible, so there is just one factor, which is noncompact. (Wolf explains the decomposition and duality on pp. 234-237.)

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler No, I am assuming the *factors* of $M$ are irreducible ($M$ is a non-compact reducible simply connected symmetric space $M= \mathbb{R^n}\times\prod M_i \times \prod M_j^* \times \prod N_k \times \prod N_l^*$). I am asking if the irreducible factors of the non-compact space are compact by the so-called "duality".

Comment: I was referring to the title question, where $M$ is irreducible. If not, and $M$ is still non-compact simply-connected, then there may (not *must*) be compact factors. But not “by the duality”, which is only a device reducing the classification of noncompact irreducibles to that of compact irreducibles. Unless I am missing something...

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler I see where the confusion is. I thought you meant $M$ is a reducible simply connected symmetric space. What do you mean by "if $M$ is still non-compact simply-connected, then **there may (not must) be** compact factors"? Sorry for the confusion. Do you mean that if there are irreducible non compact factors, they can be changed to irreducible compact factors? I cannot access pages 234-237.

Comment: Yes. Not “changed” in the sense of modifying $M$, only in the sense of bijecting them to something already-classified. As to “may (not *must*)” it was in reference to the “must” your very first comment above. E.g. $\smash{\mathbf R^2\times\mathrm S^2}$ is noncompact with a compact factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reference from which I learned the lists of $G/K$'s of various sorts is S. Helgason's book "Differential Geometry and Symmetric Spaces".

(For my own mathematical purposes, explicit details about at least the "classical groups and domains" is very useful, so I do keep these things in my head.) Possibly dropping overt reference to the anomalous isogenies and edge cases and quibbles about notational conventions...

Type A: $SL_n(\mathbb R)/SO(n,\mathbb R)$, $SL_n(\mathbb C)/SU(n)$, $SL_n(\mathbb H)/Sp^*(n)$, $U(p,q)/U(p)\times U(q)$

Types B,D: $O(p,q,\mathbb R)/O(p)\times O(q)$, $O(n,\mathbb C)/SO(n,\mathbb R)$, $O^*_{2n}/U(n)$.

Type C: $Sp_n(\mathbb C)/Sp^*n$, $Sp_n(\mathbb R)/U(n)$, $Sp^*_{p,q}/Sp^*_p\times Sp^*_q$.

The not-well-known cases are: $Sp^*_{p,q}$ is (modeled by) the group of quaternion matrices preserving a quaternion hermitian form. Provably, these have *signatures*, much as Sylvester's inertia theorem for quadratic forms. And $O^*_{2n}$ is quaternion matrices preserving a skew-hermitian form.

Note that in all cases the three $\mathbb R$-algebras $\mathbb R, \mathbb C, \mathbb H$ play roles. In fact, a completely parallel thing happens for classical groups over $p$-adic fields and in other cases, as in A. Weil's "Algebras with involutions and classical groups", Indian (not Indiana) J. Math. 1960.